# Counting right angled triangles

Tags: c++, algorithm

If you're given a set of points and you need to find the number of right angled triangles which can be made with those points(with two sides parallel to the x and y axis), what would be an efficient way to do it?

I came up with some code which checks to see whether a line is available at each given point(except for some individual points which I get rid off)

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    vector<int> storex[100010];
    vector<int> storey[100010];
    vector< pair< int,int > > singlepoints;
    vector<int> canstorex;
    int pointsx[100010];
    int pointsy[100010];
    vector<int> canstorey;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int x,y;
        cin>>x>>y;
        storex[x].push_back(y);
        storey[y].push_back(x);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<100010;i++){
        if(storex[i].size()>1){
            /*if(storex[i].size() == 1){
                singlepoints.push_back(make_pair(i,storex[i][0]));
            }*/   
            canstorex.push_back(i);
            pointsx[i] = storex[i].size();
        }
        if(storey[i].size()>1){
            /*if(storey[i].size() == 1){
                singlepoints.push_back(make_pair(storex[i][0],i));
            }*/
            canstorey.push_back(i);
            pointsy[i] = storey[i].size();
        }
    }
    int count = 0;
    for(int i =0;i<canstorex.size();i++){
        int temp = canstorex[i];
        //std::cout<<storex[temp].size()<<endl;
        for(int j =0;j<storex[temp].size();j++){
            int tempcount = 0;
            if(storey[storex[temp][j]].size()>1){
                //std::cout<<pointsx[temp]<<endl;
                tempcount+=(storey[storex[temp][j]].size()-1);

                if(pointsx[temp]>2){

                    tempcount*= (pointsx[temp]-1);

                }
                if(pointsy[storex[temp][j]]>2){

                    tempcount*= (pointsy[storex[temp][j]]-1);

                }
            }
            count +=tempcount;


        }
    }
    std::cout<<count;
    /*for(int i =0;i<canstorey.size();i++){

    }*/
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Does your code work, or not? Is it just not as efficient as you'd like?

Comment: it doesn't work for some test cases

Comment: N<=100000 in this case

Comment: Do x and y coordinates are restricted to a relatively small range or can be arbitrary large? You probably want to optimize according the expected data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your points are integers and you want only triangles that have one side parallel to x-axis, another side parallel to y-axis and a third side connecting the 2 points that were not the intersection of both side, then I would sort the data on x in a container and the data on y in another container.

For the first container, I would also sort in y points that are matching in x. The comparison functor would look like:

```
class CompareXY
{
    bool operator()(const &Point lhs, const &Point rhs) const
    {
        return lhx.x != rhs.x ? lhs.x < rhs.x : lhs.y < rhs.y;
    }
};
```

For the second container, you would reverse the comparison (`class CompareYX`).

Then you would loop over x. For each x such that has at least one another point with the same x (you should count them — see below), I would count the number of points having the same y (but a different x).

You could use `std::equal_range` to find the range with a given y and then use `std::count_if` to count the number of points that are valid to make a right triangle.

At that point, you multiply the number of points from the above two counting steps and add that to your cumulative number of triangles.

**The fact that you have properly sorted the data allows you to limit the number of checks that are made as for each x or y.**

Once you have done that, you might be able to do some extra optimisation depending on your data. Things you might want to consider would be:

- Is it useful to sort data on both x and y for both containers?
- Could some `std::equal_range` be replaced by `std::lower_bound`?
- Could you do some extra filtering at some steps to eliminate some data or some checks.
- If you have a lot of duplicated points, you might want to check them and multiply the result for that point with the number of identical points.

One thing you might try would be to do more agressive filtering initially. I am not sure if it would help. You have to measure performance. One idea would be:

- You sort on y and remove any point that does not have any matching y (cannot be part of any right triangle with sides parallel to axes).
- You copy that data and the sort on x and remove any point that does not have a matching x.

In that case, I would probably do the combined (y then x **or** x then y) sort initially to avoid extra sorting.

By the way performance might vary a lot depending on the data. So it might be a good idea to measure the performance with actual data to see its effect. In x or y coordinate range is large (say more than a few thousands), you would have very few right angle triangles so agressive initial filtering would probably be useful to reduce data size sooner and thus improve performance for remaining steps. On the other hand if data is compacted in x and y coordinates, initial filtering would be a waste of time since most data would be kept anyway and thus rechecked later anyway.